# My server favorites and history are gone!

Tags: steam, source-engine, steam-cloud

I got on Steam one day to realize that my favorites and history were completely cleared. I may have a backup, though. How do I restore it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to bring back a backup copy of the file at `Steam\userdata\<id>\7\remote\serverbrowser_hist.vdf`.

Note that if you just replace the favorites list in `Steam\userdata\<id>\7\remote\serverbrowser_hist.vdf` with your backup and restart Steam, it just gets replaced with the newer version with everything cleared. That's because `remotecache.vdf` has a hash, time, and date of the newer file and asks Steam for that newer copy when it finds an old copy of our file.

In order to tell Steam that we actually have the newer copy, we'll need to exit Steam and  "touch" `serverbrowser_hist.vdf` so that Steam believes that it was just modified and that it needs to sync with the cloud to upload those changes. To do this, open Command Prompt and type this in to go to the folder that contains `serverbrowser_hist.vdf`:

`cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\[your id]\7\remote`

After we go to the folder, we'll [update the "date modified" time to the current time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/923927/2958458):

`copy serverbrowser_hist.vdf /B+ ,,/Y`

Start Steam, and you're all set!

Comment: Thank you so much! I would hate to manually input 150 favourite servers! Life saver.

Comment: Doesn't look like this works any more. Steam still loads an old/empty favourites list from elsewhere.